# If class A contains a strong reference to class B and class B has a weak reference to class A, why does A always get deinit before B?

Tags: swift, automatic-ref-counting, retaincount

```swift
class A {
    var b: B
    
    init(b: B) {
        self.b = b
    }
    
    deinit {
        print("  Destroying A")
    }
}

class B {
    weak var a: A?
    
    deinit {
        print("  Destroying B")
    }
}

func setup(_ a: inout A?, _ b: inout B?) {
    b = B()
    a = A(b: b!)
    b?.a = a
}

var bravo: B?
var alpha: A?
setup(&alpha, &bravo)

bravo = nil
alpha = nil

// OUTPUT:
// "  Destroying A"
// "  Destroying B"
```

I've tried all permutations of setting `alpha` and `bravo` to nil, and yet I cannot get `bravo` to deinit before `alpha`. Based on my brief experiment in Swift Playgrounds, `alpha` always gets deinit before `bravo`. Can someone please explain why?

I know this has to do with ARC, but I thought if `bravo = nil`, then isn't the value of `alpha.b` also nil? If so, then wouldn't it be safe to deinit `bravo` safely before `alpha`?

I'd love to know what the retain counts are on each of these instances over time.

Comment: You can't test these kinds of thing in Playgrounds. The Playgrounds environment has its own references to objects in order to display the right-hand gutter. If you want to explore this, explore it in a command-line app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understood the question, but I see this as quite straight forward application of [ARC rules](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html). After the line

```
setup(&alpha, &bravo)
```

you have

- 2 strong references to the object `bravo` (the `bravo` itself, and its reference `alpha.b`)
- 1 strong (`alpha` itself), and 1 weak (`bravo.a`) reference to the object `alpha`

Now you set `bravo = nil`, removing 1 strong reference, but the other strong reference remains, so `deinit` is not called, based on rule:

> ARC will not deallocate an instance as long as at least one active reference to that instance still exists.

Next you set `alpha = nil`. That's deleting its only strong reference, hence based on rule

> A weak reference is a reference that doesn’t keep a strong hold on the instance it refers to, and so doesn’t stop ARC from disposing of the referenced instance.

A can be deallocated immediately. Also important to remember that

> ARC automatically sets a weak reference to nil when the instance that it refers to is deallocated

In other words, the order of operations is:

1. String reference is deleted with `alpha = nil`
2. Since there are no other strong references, all weak references are set to `nil`
3. `deinit` is called

So now, that `alpha` is deleted, no references of any kind are left for `bravo`, and hence its `deinit` can be called.

Comment: Exactly the answer I was looking for. Thank you!